# vuejs materializecss timepicker not get value

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, materialize

**How can I get time value using materializecss Timepicker in Vuejs**

[Meterilize css Time Picker Jsfiddle LInk](https://jsfiddle.net/5695gq28/4/)

It's give me value in jsfiddle but when I doing it my vuejs project it's not working..

**Vue.js Code:**

```
  <v-text-field
    name="start-time"
    id="edit_start-time"
    class="timepicker"
   ></v-text-field>



mounted() {
       $('.timepicker').pickatime({
        default: 'now', // Set default time: 'now', '1:30AM', '16:30'
        fromnow: 0, // set default time to *
        twelvehour: true, // Use AM/PM or 24-hour format
        donetext: 'OK', // text for done-button
        cleartext: 'Clear', // text for clear-button
        canceltext: 'Cancel', // Text for cancel-button
        autoclose: false, // automatic close timepicker
        ampmclickable: true, // make AM PM clickable
        aftershow: function() {} //Function for after opening timepicker
        });
      $('.timepicker').on('change', function() {
         let receivedVal = $(this).val();
          console.log(receivedVal);
        });

    },
```

**NB:** My fiddle works fine and if you check console it give me value but same code not work in Vue.js Project my Problem in Vuejs.. i want to get value like jsfiddle

Comment: Your fiddle works fine. what exactly does not work?

Comment: Yes My fiddle works fine and if you check console it give me value but same code not work in **Vue.js** Project my Problem in Vuejs.. i want to get value like jsfiddle

Comment: Please add your vuejs code

Comment: @AmrAly I was give it in my Question

Comment: Sorry I meant as a snippet so it's easy to debug

Comment: @AmrAly Thanks I got solution by making jsfiddle Snipper or live link for you.

Answer (score 4):

Please use

> v-model.lazy="deliverySchedule"

worked for me !!!

Comment: More information here -> https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy
Apparently the event change gets triggered after updating via pickatime.js instead of the input even.

Answer (score 1):

[Jsfiddle Link With Solution own my problem](https://jsfiddle.net/cckLd9te/193/)

I got solution by use `input`

`<input  class="timepicker" v-model="deliverySchedule" >`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use jQuery for this.
Vue offers some nice bindings wich are working way better.

```
<v-time-picker v-model="myTimeValue"></v-time-picker>
```

In this code i bind myTimeValue (a local data variable) to the actual value of the timepicker. Now i can use it anywhere and vue deals with all updating stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `ref`

If you need directly access a child component in JavaScript you have to assign a reference ID to the child component using ref.
For more information take a look at [Link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs).

How to use:

Your `html` should be similar to this:

```
<div class="input-field inline">
    <label for="startDate" class="materialize-label">Start Date</label>
    <input id="startDate" ref="startDate" type="date" size="12" class="startDate timepicker">
</div>
```

You also need to initialize it with jquery (the same way you have done it)

```
$('.timepicker').pickatime({
    ...
    ...
    ...
})
```

For example, when your user submits a form you just need to use: `this.$refs.startDate.value`
This will grab the value of the date.

If you want to **bind** changes from the user you can use `v-model`.
Otherwise, I think using v-model is unnecessary.

Vue Docs:

> You can use the v-model directive to create two-way data bindings on
> form input and textarea elements. It automatically picks the correct
> way to update the element based on the input type

More information at: [Link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)